# Why do my lights turn on when I plug a device into a nearby outlet?

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, recessed-lighting

I noticed that when i use the plugs in the wall like by plugging my laptop, it turns my dimmer lights on, what may have the cause of this problem and how can i fix it ? please help

Comment: Can you give us photos of the insides of the switch, light, and receptacle boxes involved? I suspect some stuff got wired in series when it shouldn't have here...

Comment: What kind of dimmer is it?  Is there a remote control? Or does it have a load sensing control like X10 dimmers often have?

Comment: is it a touch dimmer?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a remotely controlled dimmer, it's likely that RF interference from the switching power supply is causing the issue.

You may need an [AC mains RF filter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002M5OJI), AKA a noise filter, and possibly an [RF choke (ferrite core filter)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016XE2BS0) for the line cord, cord to the laptop, or both. You can probably find them in a local hardware store or electronics shop, as well as online.